# All collisions working except for one. What do I do?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, collision-detection

I have a square consisting of four different colors in the middle of my scene. At the same time, I have smaller squares of the same color randomly generated from each sides of the scene with the intention of colliding with the square in the middle. (Blue to blue, yellow to yellow, etc).

With that being said, 3 out of four of my collisions are working just fine. Red hits red fine, blue hits blue fine and yellow hits yellow fine but my green square just doesn't want to do what it should. This is how I have my collisions set up:

```
  struct PhysicsCatagory {
     static let FirstPerson : UInt32 = 0x1 << 1
     static let SecondPerson : UInt32 = 0x1 << 2
     static let ThirdPerson : UInt32 = 0x1 << 4
     static let FourthPerson : UInt32 = 0x1 << 8
  }

  smallBlue.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.FirstPerson
  smallBlue.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.SecondPerson

  smallRed.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.ThirdPerson
  smallRed.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.FourthPerson
  smallRed.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0

  smallGreen.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.ThirdPerson
  smallGreen.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.FourthPerson
  smallGreen.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0

  bigRed.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.FourthPerson
  bigRed.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.ThirdPerson
  bigRed.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0

  bigGreen.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.ThirdPerson
  bigGreen.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.FourthPerson
  bigGreen.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0

  bigBlue.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.FirstPerson
  bigBlue.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.SecondPerson
  bigBlue.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0

  bigYellow.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.FirstPerson
  bigYellow.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
  bigYellow.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.SecondPerson

  func didBeginContact() {
      let firstBody = contact.bodyA.node as! SKSpriteNode // registering as big blue square
      let secondBody = contact.bodyB.node as! SKSpriteNode // register ing as little blue square

      if firstBody.color == secondBody.color { //if the colors collide, remove small one from the scene
        //firstBody.removeFromParent()
          label.text = "\(numPoints)" // points label increment
          numPoints++ //points label increment 
          secondBody.removeFromParent()
      }

      if firstBody.color != secondBody.color { // if colors don't match, call gameOver scene
        //gameOver()
      }

      let thirdBody = contact.bodyA.node as! SKSpriteNode
      let fourthBody = contact.bodyB.node as! SKSpriteNode

      if thirdBody.color ==  fourthBody.color {           
        label.text = "\(numPoints)"
        numPoints++
        fourthBody.removeFromParent()
      }

      if thirdBody.color != fourthBody.color {
        //gameOver()
      }

      let fifthBody = contact.bodyA.node as! SKSpriteNode
      let sixthBody = contact.bodyB.node as! SKSpriteNode

      if fifthBody.color ==  sixthBody.color {            
        label.text = "\(numPoints)"
        numPoints++
        secondBody.removeFromParent()
      }

      let seventhBody = contact.bodyA.node as! SKSpriteNode
      let eighthBody = contact.bodyB.node as! SKSpriteNode

      if seventhBody.color == eighthBody.color {
          label.text = "\(numPoints)"
          numPoints++
          eighthBody.removeFromParent()
          print("green removed")
      }        
  }
```

Is there something I'm missing? Will post more code if necessary.

Here is an english representation of what I am looking for

```
if small red equals big red then gain a point, update the label, and remove small red

if small blue equals big blue then gain a point, update the labelm and remove small blue

if small yellow equals big yellow then gain a point, update points label and remove little yellow.

if small green equals big green, gain point and update label and remove little yellow from scene

if little blue does not equal big blue, call game over scene

if little yellow does not equal big yellow, call game over scene

if little red does not equal big red, call game over scene

if little green does not equal big green, call game over scene
```

Comment: this code makes no sense,  you do the same things over and over and you magically expect the seventh and eighth colors to be green.  Do me a favor,  using english, not code, (but structure it like code) explain what you want done, and I will help you create the proper logic

Comment: Im sure you saw my last question and what I am trying to do, so basically I want the small rectangles to remove themselves from the scene upon collision with the matching color.

Comment: But i want you to write this in english, so that you can learn what your are coding

Comment: I know exactly what I'm coding. I just wanted to know if i was missing something minor.

Comment: I am not trying to offend you here, but the code you just posted shows you have no idea what you are writing,  this is why i need you to write it in english, so that i can show you how to translate it into code

Comment: Added some to get an idea. See if it makes sense to you.

Comment: No, comments still make no sense because your code is wrong,  right now when red hits red, you get 4 pts, because 1st body is the same body as 3rd, 5th, and 7th,  so all you are doing in this code, is checking if red == red 4 times

Comment: whether a node is green or not, has no bearing on this code

Comment: Okay well I'm just going off of my question from yesterday. The answer that I got seemed pretty legitimate and worked fine.

Comment: you do not know how to apply it though,  this is why I need you to write what you want in an english format, so that I can teach you how to apply it

Comment: Im so freaking lost now.

Comment: I am going to edit your question with the start of what I need,  please finish it

Comment: so when the different colors combine you do not do anything different?  What I mean is, if red == red, gain 1 point, if blue == blue, gain 1 life. if green == green turbo

Comment: Yes, that is the whole logic of the game and if red hits like yellow, the game ends.

Comment: ok, now I can explain my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How the contact bodies work, is  didBeginContact will be called everytime 2 nodes collide,  that is, in 1 update cycle, if red hits blue, and red hits green, 2 calls to didBeginContact will take place.  This means that your creation of thirdBody and so fourth have no meaning, because it ends up being the same as firstBody every time.  This means that we can delete all that code entirely, and have it like this:

```
func didBeginContact() {
    let firstBody = contact.bodyA.node as! SKSpriteNode // registering as big blue square
    let secondBody = contact.bodyB.node as! SKSpriteNode // register ing as little blue square

    if firstBody.color == secondBody.color { //if the colors collide, remove small one from the scene
        label.text = "\(numPoints)" // points label increment
        numPoints++ //points label increment 
        secondBody.removeFromParent()
    }
    if firstBody.color != secondBody.color { // if colors don't match, call gameOver scene
    //gameOver()
    }


}
```

What this code says is I do not care what the 2 objects are, if a red object hits a red object, lets remove the second object.

Ok, but now we have a problem, what if the second object is the big red.

We need to program our code so that second object is always small red.  This is where the categories come in.  The category is an integer representation of what this object should be.

If we make our bigger object category masks lower than our smaller object category masks,  we could write a formula like this:

```
let firstBody = ((contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask <= contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask) ? contact.bodyA.node : contactBodyB.node) as! SKSpriteNode // registering as big blue square
let secondBody = ((contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask <= contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask) ? contact.bodyB.node : contactBodyA.node) as! SKSpriteNode // registering as little blue square
```

which says let firstBody be the node of bodyA if A <= B or else bodyB if A > B  and let secondBody be the node of bodyB if A <= B or else bodyA if A > B.

The way you have categoryBitMasks done now, it is not possible.  You will have to create bitmasks so that your larger objects and smaller objects do not share the same mask.

Now we have our order preserved, so our code says exactly what we are looking for.

If you want to add a print out of what color was removed, then we just do a condition afterwards to check the color.  See below for the final result.

```
func didBeginContact() {
    let firstBody = ((contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask <= contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask) ? contact.bodyA.node : contactBodyB.node) as! SKSpriteNode // registering as big blue square
    let secondBody = ((contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask <= contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask) ? contact.bodyB.node : contactBodyA.node) as! SKSpriteNode // registering as little blue square

    if firstBody.color == secondBody.color { //if the colors collide, remove small one from the scene
        label.text = "\(numPoints)" // points label increment
        numPoints++ //points label increment 

        if(secondBody.color == UIColor.greenColor())
        {
           print("Green was removed")
        }

        if(secondBody.color == UIColor.redColor())
        {
           print("Red was removed")
        }

        if(secondBody.color == UIColor.blueColor())
        {
           print("Blue was removed")
        }

        if(secondBody.color == UIColor.yellowColor())
        {
           print("Yellow was removed")
        }


        secondBody.removeFromParent()
    }
    if firstBody.color != secondBody.color { // if colors don't match, call gameOver scene
    //gameOver()
    }




}
```

Now keep in mind,  you never bother checking the type of collision that is happening,  so if you decide in the future to add medium red that kills you on a color match,  this will cause problems.  Because in its current state,  we only care that red hits red, we do not care if it was medium or small.  So you need to use that switch method we talked about in your other question to first check what type of collision happened,  before doing any processing:

```
func didBeginContact() {
    let firstBody = ((contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask <= contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask) ? contact.bodyA.node : contactBodyB.node) as! SKSpriteNode // registering as big blue square
    let secondBody = ((contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask <= contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask) ? contact.bodyB.node : contactBodyA.node) as! SKSpriteNode // registering as little blue square


    switch(firstBody.categoryBitMask | secondBody.categoryBitMask)
    {
        case BigObject | SmallObject:

        if firstBody.color == secondBody.color { //if the colors collide, remove small one from the scene
            label.text = "\(numPoints)" // points label increment
            numPoints++ //points label increment 

            if(secondBody.color == UIColor.greenColor())
            {
               print("Green was removed")
            }

            if(secondBody.color == UIColor.redColor())
            {
               print("Red was removed")
            }

            if(secondBody.color == UIColor.blueColor())
            {
               print("Blue was removed")
            }

            if(secondBody.color == UIColor.yellowColor())
            {
               print("Yellow was removed")
            } 


            secondBody.removeFromParent()
        }
        if firstBody.color != secondBody.color { // if colors don't match, call gameOver scene
        //gameOver()
        }

        default:()
    }




}
```

Comment: This is wonderful. Thank you very much. I really do appreciate your patience.

Comment: Explaining your logic in english helps everyone try to understand where you are going, and see what is being done wrong with your logic

Comment: I changed up everything including my bitMasks and whatnot and my green nodes still refuse to cooperate. Im stuck.

Comment: Post your changes to your bitmasks and the green objects physics bodies in your question at the bottom

Comment: Just posted them in a separate question.